Combining 2 norm tables with common columns
I have a test that consists of subtests. After the user answers the questions the total of each subtest is calculated. The total is then used against norm tables to get specific data. This is one of the tables: Screenshot
The tables in the middle are the subtests and the values are the total raw score. From this one, I get %ile Rank and Scaled score for each subtest.
The 2nd table looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/L9fDCnL
From this table, I get Grade equivalent and Age equivalent for each subtest.
As you see both tables have the same columns in the middle. I want to combine both tables to have the 4 different columns %ile Rank, Scaled score, Grade equivalent, Age equivalent, and the common columns in one table.
Excel files can be found here: https://filetransfer.io/data-package/Aebi2vRr#link
I tried to save the tables in Excel and use PhpSpreadsheet to combine both tables:
$spreadsheet1 = IOFactory::load('file1.xlsx');
$spreadsheet2 = IOFactory::load('file2.xlsx');

$worksheet1 = $spreadsheet1->getActiveSheet();
$worksheet2 = $spreadsheet2->getActiveSheet();

$data1 = $worksheet1->toArray();
$data2 = $worksheet2->toArray();

$combined = array_combine($data1, $data2);

but that's not the result I seek. I want to combine the tables logically using the common columns.
The output should look like this:
%ile Rank | Elison | Blending words | .. | Scaled score | Age equivalent | Grade equivalent
<1        | -      | -              | .. | 1            | -              | -
<1        | -      | -              | .. | 2            | -              | -
..        | ..     | ..             | .. | ..           | ..             | ..
16        | -      | 0              | .. | 7            | <4.0           | <K.O
25        | 0      | 1              | .. | 8            | <4.0           | <K.O

